# How to split dataframe, create new variable in each list dataframe, and unsplit?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am trying to split a dataframe, create a new variable in each dataframe list object, and reassemble (unsplit) the original dataframe.

The new variable I am trying to create scales the variable `B.2` from 0 to 1 for each factor level in the variable `Type`.

```
BWRX$B.2 <- BWRX$B #Create a new version of B
BWRX.Split <- split(BWRX, BWRX$Type) #Split by Type
BWRX.Split.BScaled <-lapply(BWRX.Split, function(df){df$B.3 <- (df$B.2-min(df$B.2))/(max(df$B.2)-min(df$B.2))}) #Scale B.2
```

The above code returns a list with the values of `B.2` correctly scaled within each factor level. The tricky part is that I cannot figure out how to add this variable to each dataframe in `BWRX.Split`.

I thought `df$B.3` would correct for this, but it has not. Once `B.3` is a part of each dataframe can `unsplit(, Type)` be used to reassemble the dataframes or would `do.call` be better? I was trying to combine unsplit and split so everything would be in one line to code. Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it clear what the input is and what is the desired output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't really need to `split` it, this can be done using `ave` from `base R`.  The advantage is that the new column will added in the same order as in the original row order of the dataset.

```
transform(BWRX, BScaled = ave(B.2, Type, 
        FUN = function(x) (x- min(x))/(max(x)- min(x))))
```

---

This is a group by operation.  So, it can be efficiently done with `data.table` or `dplyr`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(BWRX)[, BScaled := (B.2 - min(B.2))/(max(B.2) - min(B.2)), by = Type]
```

Comment: Would there be any reason to use `transform()` instead of `data.frame()`? The [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/transform.html) for `transform()` is pretty ominous.

Comment: @user3290799  It is just to the return the output without changing the original object.  If you assign it to the original object `BWRX`, it will reflect that in the object

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned and MrFlick confirmed, you can simply `unsplit()` it:

```
BWRX$B.3 <- unsplit(BWRX.Split.BScaled,BWRX$Type)
```

To do this in a single line:

```
BWRX$B.3 <- unsplit(lapply(split(BWRX$B.2, BWRX$Type), function(x)(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))),BWRX$Type)
```

But Akrun's solutions are both quicker